How to specify the starting read position for parquet files？
I want to use multithread to read a parquet file, where each thread starts reading different data segments from the specified start and end positions without interfering with each other. Currently, I have not found a suitable solution to this problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
